# How do you load balance Peoplesoft report repositories?

Tags: peoplesoft

When setting up a load balanced Peopletools/Peoplesoft environment( 2 web, 2 app, 2 process schedulers, all on separate hardware), how do you configure the report repository/repositories? The intent is to have two totally indepenent stacks but also allow reports run on one side to be available from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a single report repository that is on a shared area accessible to both sides/sets of the stack.  I've never tried having 2 report repositories, but it sounds like a replication nightmare. If it can be done I'd be interested to hear more.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary, but required in case you have load on report nodes.

This can be achieved by creating two report nodes with differrent domain names and needs to be configured through web server config file. Please don't forget to make one report node master and second one slave.

Thanks